# Input content inside the object drawn in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, printing

I have a multitude of rectangles drawn in my map composer.
I have also separate text boxes for them.

[image]

I am wondering about the possibility of including the text content for drawn rectangles or other shapes. Is it possible?

Comment: No problem. WIll know in the future.

Comment: Do you mean to add a text to shape or to have a text with border?

Comment: Add text to a shape

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean to insert text inside a shape, as in Office Word. It is not possible to include a text content for layout shapes because they don't have any property for text.

Eventually you will need to use auxiliary items (separate textbox) or
you can add a font symbol layer for the shape as follows:

- Click "Style" box.

  [image]
- Add a new symbol layer. Select "Centroid Fill".

  [image]
- Change "Simple Marker" to "Font Marker".

  [image]
- Set "Size" and "Characters"

  [image]

[image]

Comment: I have never thought about it this way! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a border to your textboxes and style it, as you wish. No need to draw rectangles in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You also could place the textbox into your triangle (or rectangle) and select them both.
Then you group them with
CRTL + g:
[image: textbox and geometry selected via mouse an gouped via CRTL + g]

While moving one of those the other one follows.
To rewrite your text in the textbox without ungrouping the pair before (this would be SHIFT + CRTL + g) you just singularily select you textbox in the elements-panel:
[image: singularily selected textbox out of group and rewriting the content of the textbox]